# Best way to avoid many if else statements in java

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a method which is implemented as below

```
public void setAttributes(Data d) {
  Model m;
  String type = d.getType();
  if (type.equals("TYPE1")) {
    m.setType(type);
    m.setDuration(d.getDuration())
    m.setBenefit(d.getBenefit())
    m.setPermission(d.getPermission());
  } else if (type.equals("TYPE2")) { /* Here we wont be having duration, benefit */
    m.setType(type);
    m.setLab(true)
  }
}
```

This doesnot look scalable because in future if some more TYPES comes, then we need to keep adding if else blocks. Is there any way I can refactor this.
Note: Attributes will be different based on types.

Comment: Using a `switch` construct here seems like a better option provided you plan on adding more options.

Comment: You can change type to enum and make switch from if-else statements. Or you can check *visitor* pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a subclass of `Data` per each type and use overriding to attach the behavior to each class individually. This makes sense if you plan to have very many data types and a lot of associated logic.

```
public abstract class Data {
    ...
    public abstract void setAttributes(Model m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining an `enum` for possible types.

Change the *type* of `getType()` to that `enum`.

Convert your `if` block to a `switch` block that switches on that `enum`.

Using a `String` is a weaker implementation technique since it's not quite so *type-safe* if you get my meaning.

Comment: How does this scale? Now you keep adding case statements? I wanted a solution where we can define a config/behavior in map and then use it instead of if and else

Comment: A jump to an `enum` label in a `switch` is O(1). So it scales. Maintenance is no more than adding a new `enum` type and a corresponding `case`. But do consider @MarkoTopolnik approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch`

```
switch(type) {
    case "TYPE1":
        m.setType(type);
        m.setDuration(d.getDuration())
        m.setBenefit(d.getBenefit())
        m.setPermission(d.getPermission());
        break;
    case "TYPE2":
       m.setType(type);
       m.setLab(true)
       break;
}
```

This will provide more scalable template.

Comment: Now you have to keep adding `case` labels. Not a large improvement.

Comment: How does this scale. You need to keep adding case statements?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not large improvement, but still improvement. There aren't many other options.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the switch-case statement is suiting for you (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

This means for your code example:

```
public void setAttributes(Data d) {
   Model m;
   String type = d.getType();
   switch(type) {
       case "Type1":
           m.setType(type);
           m.setDuration(d.getDuration())
           m.setBenefit(d.getBenefit())
           m.setPermission(d.getPermission());
           break;
       case "TYPE2": 
          m.setType(type);
          m.setLab(true);
          break;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps